# Consulta que retorna soma onde estados forem iguais a X e os outros agrupados

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela onde contém o valor de venda de alguns estados do Brasil, gostaria de realizar uma consulta que me retornasse o valor de venda dos estados de SP e RJ, e para os outros estados ele me retornasse a soma do que é diferente disso.

Para exemplificar imaginemos que tenho essa tabela

### Estado | Vendas

### SP | 20

### RJ | 30

### GO | 50

### PA | 30

### TO | 5

Gostaria que a consulta me retornasse
SP (20), RJ (30), Outros (85).

Sou bem iniciante em SQL e estou com um pouco de dificuldades

Com esse código consigo trazer todas as vendas separadas porém não consigo agrupar os que são diferentes de SP e RJ

```
SELECT ESTADO, SUM(VALOR_VENDA) FROM vendas GROUP BY ESTADO ORDER BY ESTADO ASC;
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar CASE / WHEN:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 'SP' THEN Vendas ELSE 0) AS SP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 'RJ' THEN Vendas ELSE 0) AS RJ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN estado <> 'SP' AND estado <> 'RJ' THEN Vendas ELSE 0) AS OUTROS
FROM sua_tabela;
```

Uma linha com três colunas com os valores desejados.

Answer (score 0):

Ou

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ESTADO NOT IN ('RJ','SP') THEN 'OUTROS' ELSE ESTADO END) ESTADO, 
       SUM(VALOR_VENDA)
 FROM vendas 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ESTADO NOT IN ('RJ','SP') THEN 'OUTROS' ELSE ESTADO END) 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ESTADO NOT IN ('RJ','SP') THEN 'OUTROS' ELSE ESTADO END) ASC
```